# Bottling in steel growlers

Tags: bottling

I want to bottle and carbonate in flip-top steel growlers. How long do you think the beer stays fresh? Any other problems that might arise?

Comment: can you link us to the growler you have or plan on using?
my concern would be are they pressure rated

Comment: @jsolarski https://www.amazon.com/Beer-Growler-Stainless-Swing-Top-Homebrew/dp/B01MQK0DTZ/

Comment: These look actually very nice. My experience with swing top bottles (33 cl, 0.5 l and 0.75 l) says that these growlers should probably keep pressure indefinitely. Added advantage of the stainless steel: ideal for Belgian and German styles with 3 to 4 volumes of CO2.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why you can't do this, just make sure you calculate priming sugar and make sure those growlers can handle the pressures you want to be at for your homebrew. [You should use a priming sugar calculator like this.](https://www.northernbrewer.com/pages/priming-sugar-calculator)

The beer will stay fresh as long as you don't open it. For upwards of a year or more.

Comment: I agree, but the product you linked I would be wary of the cap not holding pressure. Try 1, see if it carbonates........but those type of growlers are meant to be filled with pre-carbonated beer....

Comment: @jsolarski In my opinion, the glass growlers with a screw cap don't hold pressure, but these Grolsch type caps should. Anyway I just bottled the beer with added sugar enough for 2.5 volumes of co2, I'll let you know how it goes. Edit: here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwCEGsyMvPc

Comment: @JamesDavis my concern is not all stainless steel growlers are made the same, was it stamped, welded or milled...etc, how thick is the metal? since I dont have that particular one i can only make assumptions....Your right it will probably hold pressure very well, but if it feels cheap, then YMMV